# reading fields which have null value

Tags: java, arraylist, overriding, abstract-class

I have an abstract class "Homework"and 4 other classes that extend it (I only pasted one of them since they are identical). The program compiles, but the output looks like this:
null - must read 0 pages
null - must read 0 pages
null - must read 0 pages
null - must read 0 pages

What should I change to get it to work?

**Tester class**

```
  public class testHomework
  {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Homework> list = new ArrayList<Homework>();

    list.add(new MyMath(1,"Math"));
    list.add(new MyEnglish(3,"English"));
    list.add(new MyJava(3,"Java"));
    list.add(new MyScience(2,"Science"));


    for (Homework s : list) 
    {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

**Abstract class Homework**

```
 public abstract class Homework 
 {
   private int pagesToRead;
   private String typeHomework;

  {
    // initialise instance variables
    pagesToRead = 0;
    typeHomework = "none";
  }

  public Homework(int pages, String hw)
  {
      pagesToRead = pages;
      typeHomework = hw;
  }

  public abstract void createAssignment(int pages);

  public int getPages() 
 {
    return pagesToRead;
 }

  public void setPagesToRead(int p) 
 {
     pagesToRead = p;
 }

  public String getTypeHomework() 
 {
     return typeHomework;
 }

  public void setTypeHomework(String hw)
 {
     typeHomework = hw;
 }
```

**MyMath**

```
public class MyMath extends Homework 
{

 private int pagesRead;
 private String typeHomework;

 public MyMath(int pages, String hw)
 {
    super(pages,hw);
 }

 public void createAssignment(int pages) 
 {
    setTypeHomework("Math");
    setPagesToRead(pages);
 }

 public String toString() 
 {
     return typeHomework + " - must read " + pagesRead + " pages";
 }
}
```

Comment: remove the member variables (pagesRead, typeHomework) from your MyMath class - you are shadowing them. Then either move the toString method to the Homework class or use "getTypeHomework" and "getPages" in your toString method in MyMath.

Comment: Also, this isn't a 'method override return[ing] null', it is reading fields which have null value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to actually assign values to the fields `pagesRead` and `typeHomework` in `MyMath` if you want those fields to be changed.

You can only assign private fields within the same class - these are different fields to same-named fields in the parent class(es).

You can alternatively make the fields `protected` in the parent classes, and remove the fields from the subclass.